# Not able to expire the objects in s3 bucket using lifecycle rule

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have an s3 bucket with folder structure as below

```
Test/--static(default root folder)
 23-10-2023-test -- created daily
   Fleetest
     package
       test23-10-2023.txt file
 24-10-2023-test -- created daily
   Fleetest
     package
       test24-10-2023.txt file
```

need to expire the objects older than 30 days.

i tried creating a lifecycle rule for entire bucket to get objects expired which are more than 30 days but it is not working. Then i tried creating rule for folder Test/ this also not working. Is it because of the dynamic folders created daily with the object present inside it resisting the expiration of the object?

Comment: How long has it been since the 30 day expiration? Rules may take some time to take effect, after the eligible objects are marked for deletion.

Comment: it's been 5 days since we have set up the 30 days expiration and the bucket contains around an year old objects within the same above format